# Accessing two mics` on a COTS device

Tags: java, android, distance, microphone, smartphone

My issue is similar to that one : [How do I simultaneously record audio from every mic on a microphone array into a separate buffer in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8808567/how-do-i-simultaneously-record-audio-from-every-mic-on-a-microphone-array-into-a) but has slightly different requirements. Maybe there is a solution for my problem, but I can´t figure it out on my own. I absolutely **have to access two microphones on a smartphone**, or in general a hand-held device running Android OS. It does not have to be simultaneous, that´s not possible anyway, but I have to access two distinct microphones in one device.

**Do you know any solution for this issue ?**

I know how to access the mic through the Android API, but I really need two different. This will serve as a baseline for a triangulation.